# Searching fields with accented characters

Tags: mysql

I have a field which stores special characters like 'Niterói' ,'Eunápolis', etc..

How can I make a mysql search that will:

Search term : Niteroi
Matches : Niterói

Search term: Eunapolis
Matches : Eunápolis

At the moment , searching for 'Niteroi' returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collation `utf8_unicode_ci` should see them as identical:

```
WHERE ... = "Niterói" COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE TABLEA TA
 WHERE CONVERT (TA.SEARCH_COLUMN USING ascii) = 'SEARCH_TERM';
```